# how can I connect to my google cloud mysql database using a function deployed in firebase?

Tags: javascript, mysql, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I deployed this function in firebase to connect to my google cloud mysql database:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const mysql = require('mysql');

const connectionName = process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME || 'xxx';
const dbUser = process.env.SQL_USER || 'xxx';
const dbPassword = process.env.SQL_PASSWORD || 'xxx';
const dbName = process.env.SQL_NAME || 'xxx';

const mysqlConfig = {
  connectionLimit: 1,
  user: dbUser,
  password: dbPassword,
  database: dbName,
  socketPath: `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`,
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;
}

let mysqlPool;

exports.populateDatabase = functions.https.onRequest ((req, res) => {
  if (!mysqlPool) {
    mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
  }

  mysqlPool.query('SELECT * from exercise', (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  });

});
```

Then clicking on the generated link in firebase the result is this one:

> {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"/cloudsql/xxx","fatal":true}

how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The complete instructions to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Function is in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions), and are too long to simply list here.  I suggest reading over them very carefully.

One thing important thing to note is this statement from that page:

> Note: These instructions require your Cloud SQL instance to have a
>   public IP address. If you want to use a private IP address, see
>   [Configuring Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) and connect directly using the
>   private IP.

So, if you're trying to access with a private IP address, you will have to set up a VPC to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a SQL database with an external ip address then you can connect using this code. The most important step is to deploy your cloud function with the following Environment Variable: `CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME` = `your-project:us-central1:your-instance`. This will start the cloud sql proxy for you.

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */



exports.connect= (req, res) => {


  var mysql = require('mysql');



  var pool = mysql.createPool({
    socketPath: `/cloudsql/your-project:us-central1:your-instance`,
    user            : 'test',
    password        : 'root',
    database        : 'data',
    connectionLimit : 10,               // this is the max number of connections before your pool starts waiting for a release
    multipleStatements : true           // I like this because it helps prevent nested sql statements, it can be buggy though, so be careful
});




  pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
    if (err)
        return res.send(400);

    // if you got a connection...
    conn.query('SHOW DATABASES', function(err, rows) {
        if(err) {
            conn.release();
            return res.send(400, 'Couldnt get a connection');
        }

        // for simplicity, just send the rows
        res.status(200).send(rows);

        // CLOSE THE CONNECTION
        conn.release();
    })

    });




};
```

TEST THE FUNCTION:

```
[{"Database":"information_schema"},{"Database":"data"},{"Database":"mydatabase"},{"Database":"mysql"},{"Database":"performance_schema"},{"Database":"sys"}]
```